# Validating a grammar

Tags: java, string

I am trying to check whether a given string is accepted or not by using the given grammar.

In the console, I am getting Exception error like this:

```
Enter your string 
aab 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 
    at first.lab3.main(lab3.java:15)
```

This is my code:

```
package first;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab3 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("The grammer is : S->AB, A->aA, A->a,B->Bb,B->b\n ");
  System.out.print("Enter your string\n ");
  char[] charArray = str.nextLine().trim().toCharArray();
  int count, flag;
  if (charArray[0] == 'a') {
   {
    flag = 0;
   }
   for (count = 0; charArray[count] != ' '; count++) {
    if (charArray[count] == 'b') {
     flag = 1;
     continue;
    }
    if ((flag == 1) && (charArray[count] == 'a')) {
     System.out.println("Sring is not accepted");
     break;
    }
    if (charArray[count] == 'a') {
     continue;
    }
    if (flag == 1 && charArray[count] == ' ') {
     System.out.println("The string is accepted");
     break;
    }
   }
  } else {
   System.out.println("String is not accepted ");
  }
 }
}
```

Where is my fault??

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Is it not compiling, throwing an exception, or giving incorrect results?

Comment: "It is not working"... please point out whether it is a compiling error is not doing what you want?

Comment: Please read over ["How do I ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it really does matter that you've read this, and then update your question accordingly: you're asking other people to invest time in helping you, so invest the time to make sure it's a good question yourself, too.

Comment: its not working when i am giving input .

Comment: Don't forget to `str.close();` your scanner.

Comment: Well, `"aab".trim()` contains **no** spaces. So `charArray[count] != ' '` is an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the error, your input contains no spaces. Your loop never exits until an error as `count++` goes outside the bounds of the string.

Options involve not using `trim()` and adding a space after your input or follow along...

> The grammer is : S->AB

Okay, so that is `A` followed by `B`.

Where `A` is one or more `'a'`

> A->aA, A->a

And `B` is one or more `'b'`

> B->Bb,B->b

So, possible values "ab", "aaaab", "abbb", "aaaabbbb".

All this code can simply be condensed into a regular expression. `a+b+`, or "one or more 'a' followed by one or more 'b'".

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("The grammer is : S->AB, A->aA, A->a,B->Bb,B->b\n ");
  System.out.print("Enter your string\n ");
  boolean accepted = str.nextLine().matches("a+b+");

  if (!accepted) {
     System.out.println("String is not accepted ");
  } else {
      System.out.println("The string is accepted");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Obviously, if you change the grammar, you'd likely need to use the other approach

Comment: can u tell me why my code doesn't work properly?please.

Comment: Top of my answer (and the other answer) explains why your code fails

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
for(count=0;charArray[count]!=' ';count++)
```

then how can you have

```
if(flag==1 && charArray[count]==' '){
```

in your for loop?

As per @MatiasCicero comment

> you cannot check for a space character inside the for loop, because if
>   you do have a space character, you'll be out of the loop already
>   (because the loop precondition will fail)

Comment: I have updated the loop. But still having problem  


for(count=1;charArray[count-1]!=' ';count++)

Comment: and what is the `problem` ?

Comment: @AritraPaul What the answer is trying to express is that you cannot check for a space character inside the for loop, because if you do have a space character, you'll be out of the loop already (because the loop precondition will fail)

Comment: @MatiasCicero Thanks, I did not think that I needed to explain that - my bad.

Comment: if give input string 'aab'  the output should be 'The string is accepted'

Comment: I think the `else` at the end does not have an `if` on it. Something about that `{ flag = 0 }` is wrong

Comment: As per my answer, `'The string is accepted'` code can never be entered into

Comment: @Mataias Cicero Same logic is working quite good in C. So I am not getting your point